# What to do when pandas interval_range gives floating intervals

Tags: pandas

I wrote something like this:

cut_bins = pd.interval_range(start = -0.4, freq = 0.1, end = 0.8)

and it gives me this

[image: (image)]

how can I have them rounded to one decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

One answer would be to split the object, round each bound of the intervals through a loop and rebuild the `IntervalIndex`:

```
import pandas as pd

cut_bins = pd.interval_range(start = -0.4, freq = 0.1, end = 0.8)

pd.IntervalIndex([
    pd.Interval( round(i.left,1), round(i.right,1), i.closed )
    for i in cut_bins
])
```

Out:

```
IntervalIndex([(-0.4, -0.3], (-0.3, -0.2], (-0.2, -0.1], (-0.1, 0.0], (0.0, 0.1] ... (0.3, 0.4], (0.4, 0.5], (0.5, 0.6], (0.6, 0.7], (0.7, 0.8]],
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[float64]')
```